# Angularjs - Binding service data to models in many controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a simple [example](http://codepen.io/snater/pen/mHsAt), what I want achieve, is when the text field is changed, both models should change. Is this possible without using $watch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make the object pass by reference instead of passing the string value..

See this solution

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dczmp

```
<div ng-controller="first">
    <input type="text" ng-model="testModel.test_var" />
    <p>{{testModel.test_var}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="second">
    <p>{{testModel.test_var}}</p>
</div>
```

In your controllers :

```
$scope.testModel = Data
```

instead of

```
$scope.testModel = Data.test_var
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can bind the root object, like in [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmzoi) example.

So your controllers do this:
Controller "first":
`$scope.testModel = Data`
Controller "second":
`$scope.testModel = Data`

Now, you use this as `<input ng-model="testModel.test_var"/>` and in both views you use this:

```
 <p>{{testModel.test_var}}</p>
```

Comment: Ah, now I see that @ganaraj has the same answer :)